# Cant get and show textarea value

Tags: javascript, textarea

HTML code:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Book return comment (optional):</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <textarea id="comment" class="form-control" rows="6" maxlength="500" placeholder="Please limit your comment to 500 characters."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" id="btn-confirm" class="btn">Confirm</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
  <div id="commentField">
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function getComment () {
var comment = $('#comment').val();
$('#commnetField').html(comment);
}

$('#btn-confirm').click(function() {
});
```

I am new at jQuery, what's wrong with this code? I want to get textarea text and show it in div with id='commentField'.

Comment: You could correct the typo in this: `$('#commnetField').html(comment);`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your JS (`#commnetField` rather than `#commentField`). And what exactly do you want to achieve on a button click? Currently you are doing nothing.

```
function getComment () {
  var comment = $('#comment').val();
  $('#commentField').html(comment);
}

$('#btn-confirm').click(function() { });
```

If you want to set the textbox on the button click you have to change it to.

```
$('#btn-confirm').click(getComment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've just mistaken. You've set "empty" function as "click" event handler of #btn-confirm. There should be you getComment function, e.g.

```
$('#btn-confirm').on('click', getComment)
```